# Given any finite string of number, is it true there exists a perfect square whose leading numbers are the string

Tags: algebra-precalculus, decimal-expansion

Given any finite string of number, is it true there exists a perfect square whose leading numbers are the string? For example, given the string 123456, can I find a perfect square with leading digits 123456?

I think the answer is a positive one because number of integers with the string are infinite so one can keep increasing the number to obtain a perfect square?  Appreciate all advice, thank you

Comment: The number of such integers being infinite is completely irrelevant. There are infinitely many integers that end with $3$, but exactly none of them are perfect squares.

Comment: This question is a slightly more general form of the question http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1493224/find-an-integer-such-that-when-squared-the-first-4-digits-are-6666

Answer (score 4):

The answer is yes. In fact, we can find infinitely many such perfect squares. In your particular case,
$$111,111^2=12,345,654,321$$ and $$341,364^2=123,456,660,496$$

---

Here is the proof. Let the natural number coming from the string be $a$. We want to find natural numbers $n$, $b$, and $c$ such that
$$b^2=a\cdot 10^n+c \quad\text{where}\quad 0\le c<10^n$$

This makes $b^2$ a perfect square with the leading digits of $a$.

For all $n$ let $d_n=\lfloor \sqrt{a\cdot 10^n} \rfloor$, where the symbol is the greatest integer function. Then clearly 
$$d_n+1=\sqrt{a\cdot 10^n}+r \quad\text{for some real $0<r\le 1$},$$
$$(d_n)^2\le a\cdot 10^n,\quad\text{and}$$
$$(d_n+1)^2> a\cdot 10^n$$

We get

$$\begin{align}
(d_n+1)^2 &= (\sqrt{a\cdot 10^n} +r)^2 \\
  &=a\cdot 10^n+ 2r\sqrt{a\cdot 10^n}+r^2
\end{align}$$

We can find some $n$ such that $2r\sqrt{a\cdot 10^n}+r^2<10^n$ since the right hand side of that inequality grows to infinity more rapidly than the left hand side as $n\to+\infty$.

Then we choose that $n$, let $b=d_n+1$ and $c=(d_n+1)^2-a\cdot 10^n$. That gives us what we want. In fact, any larger $n$ also works, so there are infinitely many choices.

I used that technique to find the two cases given at the top of this answer.

Answer (score 2):

There is a well-known algorithm for extracting the square root of a number.
Treating your desired string of digits as an integer, add $1$,
then use the standard square-root algorithm to compute the square root to
a sufficient number of digits.
The result (an approximate square root)
is a decimal number whose square is the desired
string of digits followed by some other digits.
Multiply this approximate square root by a suitable power of $10$ so that the
result is an integer.
Now you have an integer whose square starts with the desired string of digits.

[Full details and justification of the algorithm can be found in an earlier answer to a related question.](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1495943)